# Асинхронный вызов функций Java Script

Tags: jquery, javascript, асинхронность

```
user.on("read", function(data, cb) {
        redis_cli.hmset('messages:' + data.id, { read : 1});
        redis_cli.incrby("USER:UNREAD:" + data.idUser, -1, function (err, Ctr) {
            number = Ctr;
        });
        cb(number);
    });
```

Нужно сделать асинхронный возврат значения **Ctr** для **cb()**

Comment: а откуда у вас возьмется cb ? где вы объявили функцию на которую он якобы ссылается ? (единственное где это действительно возможно, это в методе .on() объекта user, но обычно подобные методы так не пишутся.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется так:

```
user.on("read", function(data, cb) {
    redis_cli.hmset('messages:' + data.id, { read : 1});
    redis_cli.incrby("USER:UNREAD:" + data.idUser, -1, function (err, Ctr) {
       cb(Ctr); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Разумеется, что точно не так :) Не работает

Comment: что конкретно не работает? cb не вызывается? или Ctr пустой или что? В вашем варианте вы вызываете cb еще до выполнения incrby и number будет undefined.

    user.on("read", function(data, cb) {
      console.log('1');
      redis_cli.hmset('messages:' + data.id, { read : 1});
      console.log('2');
      redis_cli.incrby("USER:UNREAD:" + data.idUser, -1, function (err, Ctr) {
        console.log('3', Ctr);
        cb(Ctr); 
      });
    });

что в консоли будет?

Comment: Вот что выдает консоль:
1
2
3 -51

Comment: Спасибо - все замечательно!

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, если ответ вам подходит - отметьте его как правильный (галка в кружочке слева от ответа)